# google maps api versions issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I have a problem regarding use of Google maps api.
When I use api source as

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.9&sensor=true&libraries=places&callback=LoadMap';

then in my application pinch to zoom is not working. or in fact sliding of map is not working properly(it slides to one direction and sometimes doesn't even slide. many issues).

but when I use api source as 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX&sensor=true&libraries=places&callback=initialize";

then pinch to zoom is working and even sliding is working properly. But if I replace this with above 'api source' then info window that I created for above api is not opening.

Any Suggestion ? What to do. Is there any other api source I should use ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 3.9 is older version and has pinch zoom broken on safari.
Try upgrading to a later version, or simply use the latest version like you have put on the non-versioned url